# Is there an alternative way to profile Metal kernels?

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I tried to use "Capture GPU Frame" to profile some Metal kernels. I ran into some weird errors, such as "Unexpected Replayer Terminated" when is about to finish, which I was not able to fix.

So, is there an alternative way to measure the times of the Metal kernels?

I am using XCode 8.3.2, with iOS 10.3.2. I cannot run in the simulator because I'm using Metal Performance Shaders.

Comment: Also tested with Xcode 8.3.3. The error code for "Unexpected Replayer Terminated" is 512.

Comment: I think the alternative would be using Xcode 9's GPU frame capture. It's supposed to be much better for compute kernels. I haven't had much luck with the Xcode 8 one, either.

Comment: The thing is that a lot has to be changed in the codebase to work in Xcode 9. But thanks, I think that's the only chance I have right now, as I also tried with Xcode 8.2 and 8.0 with no luck.